# Selection Sort in Haskell using unfoldr

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a selection sort in Haskell using `unfoldr` but my function keeps throwing type errors and I'm unsure how to fix it.

My code for the selection sort:

```
unfoldSort = unfoldr select
select [] = Nothing
select xs = Just (m, delete m xs)
   where m = minimum xs
```

This is the error message I get:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘select’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
  Relevant bindings include
    unfoldSort :: [a0] -> [a0]
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance (Ord b, Ord a) => Ord (Either a b)
      -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
    instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
    instance Ord Integer
      -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
    ...plus 23 others
    ...plus 38 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the first argument of ‘unfoldr’, namely ‘select’
  In the expression: unfoldr select
  In an equation for ‘unfoldSort’: unfoldSort = unfoldr select
```

Comment: You need to include what errors you're getting.

Comment: sorry, I've now updated

Comment: Well, firstly you should have a type signature for `select` so it's not forced to infer the type. That alone should make the errors a little clearer.

Comment: And unfold doesn't return a Maybe, does it? I thought it just returned a list.

Comment: `min` has two arguments, `minimum` has one argument (a list).

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that `unfoldSort` returns a `Maybe` when you say:

```
unfoldSort :: t -> Maybe (t, t)
```

but is that really true? Note that the return type of `unfoldSort` *must* be the same as the return type of `unfoldr` since you're just returning whatever it gives you.

`unfoldr` has the signature:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

Note it returns a list, not a `Maybe`, which means your `unfoldSort` must also just return a list.

Change your signature so it returns a list, not a `Maybe`.

Comment: sorry, realised that I wasn't meant to include that type declaration as I knew it was wrong. have updated my code and have new error messages

Comment: @Sophie Add proper signatures to both functions. It's saying it can't properly figure out what types you intend since there are many possible overloads. `minimum` requires that it's argument be a list of orderable elements, but you haven't specified that. Add a `Ord` type constraint to `select`.

Comment: Really, the signature should be one of the first things you write. You need to know what types your function takes a returns. Once you that written, all other errors become much more obvious.

Comment: Sorry but `select` isn't a separate function, `select` is within the function `unfoldSort`

Comment: @Sophie If the code you posted is your real code, then `select` is in fact a separate function. Even if it was defined in a where/let binding though, you can still add a type signature

Comment: I really don't think that `select` is a separate function. If it is, can you explain to me how my code defines `select` as a separate function to `unfoldSort` please?

Comment: @Sophie `unfoldSort = unfoldr select` defines the `unfoldSort` function. `select [] = Nothing` and the line below it define `select`. Where's the confusion stemming from?

Comment: Okay, so this is what happens when I add in the type signature:

`Could not deduce (Ord a0)
      from the context: Ord a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   select :: Ord a => [t] -> [t]
        at /Users/Sophie/Desktop/ReasoningAboutFunctionalPrograms/13032046.hs:470:11-29
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘select’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        select :: Ord a => [t] -> [t]`

Comment: @Sophie You added a type constraint but you're never using it. `select` should accept a list of orderables, since that's what `minimum` requires. In your signature, you declared the type constraint, then used `t` instead.

Comment: @Sophie And please update the question with your code and errors. It's very hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I have updated, also aware the type declarations are wrong (I am struggling with understanding them fully as I'm still learning Haskell), and the unfoldr type declarations are now really confusing me

Comment: @Sophie I hate to say this, but it might be a good idea to take a step back. To use Haskell, you *really* need to have a good grasp of its type system. You may find that it's more beneficial to write some simpler programs first. Write simple functions with different signatures until you have a good grasp. If you look on my profile, I have my email address posted. You can email me there I'd you want general help. This question is becoming increasingly offtopic for the site though.

Comment: I'd say I know enough about types, I had just made a small mistake and now have my code working.